# A book for C beginners

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I am a PHP developer, and now I want to learn C for a couple of reasons.

1. I lack knowledge in Java, as well as data structures and algorithms.
2. PHP is written in C.

The most important thing is the first reason. I don't want to get deep into C, but at least I could understand what C programs are doing. Does anyone have any good idea how I should proceed? Thanks!

Comment: You lack knowledge in Java and thus you're trying to learn C ?

Comment: @cnicutar, No, I am just saying C could facilitate understanding data structure, nothing to do with Java since they are two different styles of languages.

Comment: [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: +1. I don't know about PHP, but reading a bit about how Python is put together was beneficial to my Python. Scripting languages like Python and PHP are largely ways of plumbing together blocks of C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably the wrong approach. First learn the basic theory behind programming which is algorithms and datastructures. These are language neutral.

Than try to learn a language and its syntax to write your algorithms. To answer your question, a good book for C is [C in a Nutshell](http://www.oreilly.de/catalog/9780596006976/) but it DOES NOT teach you the basics of programming.

And then there is still the book [The C Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) by Kernighan&Ritchie, who invented C.

Comment: I tried to find a book which is language neutral for these topics, but I failed to find one. I just have to go to wikipedia to learn some theory of algorithms I find interesting.

Comment: Sure, I learned by fiddling around in one language until I hardly knew what I was doing and continued from there. I think it's always a combination of practical examples in a language and theory like in university classes on datastructures and algorithms.